# Problems with hybrid HTML5 apps when IOS/Android updates?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, html5-apps

Are there any specific problems associated with HTML5 hybrid APPs (Ionic, PhoneGab, etc.), when the smartphone's OS is updated?

Will my app for example be directly compatible with the new version OS? or will I have to wait for the used framework to updated as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no definitive answer to this. Usually everything works fine since the creators of such frameworks (as does every developer for the corresponding platform) have access to early beta versions of the new operating systems and can therefore test and update before the stable OS release, if necessary.

However, that doesn't mean that that does work out 100% of the time.